# Query about setOnClickListener() and onClick() of android

Tags: android

what is actually done by setOnClickListener() method and onClick() method during click

events.why this two method is needed during click events.

please explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

onClickListener() method lets you to handle "on click events". You can have statements below this method that will be happening when one of your objects is clicked.

You can visit [here](http://developer.android.com) to gain more knowledge about these methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `onClick()` function defined in your XML, you have to put the `onClick()` method in the current Activity. For example:

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onclick:doSomething() />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
  public class Main extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
      }

     public void doSomething(){
     //do something here
     }
  }
```

Above will only search for doSomething in Main.Java

This is important if you are using fragments, since the programmatic way of setting onclick listeners (using `setOnClickListener()`) will probably have the method handling clicks in a fragment's `onCreateView()` where it will not be found if referred to, from XML.

Answer (score 0):

`onClickListener` is an interface that allows you to use the `onClick` method. Here is a link that will describe it in more detail. Basically though, you use the `setOnClickListener` to implement the method you create.

Here is the link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 0):

@pronay biswas When you want explanation for such things just take the cursor of mouse over that text and a pop dialog will appear that will tell you about that particular thing in android if you are using eclipse

what setOnClickListener does

```
void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)



public void setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener l) 
Since: API Level 1 
Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not 
clickable, it becomes clickable.

Parameters
  The callback that will run
```

android.view.View.OnClickListener

```
// working of View.OnClickListener 


    public static interface 
    View.OnClickListener
    android.view.View.OnClickListener 
    Known Indirect Subclasses 
    CharacterPickerDialog, KeyboardView, QuickContactBadge 
    CharacterPickerDialog Dialog for choosing accented characters related to a base character.  
    KeyboardView A view that renders a virtual Keyboard.  
    QuickContactBadge Widget used to show an image with the standard QuickContact badge and on-click behavior.  



Class Overview
Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked. 

// OnClickListener

@Override


Specified by: onClick(...) in OnClickListener
public abstract void onClick (View v) 
Since: API Level 1 
Called when a view has been clicked.

Parameters
v  The view that was clicked.
```